# Julia : how to make a tree structure with vector data?

Tags: data-structures, graph, tree, julia, directed-graph

I need to implement a  tree in Julia with depth of l=3. Initially the root node has a vector of m=10000 random values (k=rand(m)).Then this vector is divided into k=10 partitions where each node child has a vector of n=1000 values. Finally the leafs  are connected to a given child node.

each partition (child node) has a certain number of leafs where each leaf has a vector of data . Since each child node has a vector of 1000 values.this latter is shared with its leafs. the total number of leafs is 100 and the number of leafs for each child may vary from one child to another.
so the structure of the tree is as follows:

level 0                           root node   : vector of 10000 values

level 1          10 child node each one of 1000 values

level 2          100 leafs

```
type MyNode{T}
  data::T
  level::Int
  child:: Vector{MyNode}
  nchilds :: Int
  nLeafs::Int      
  leafs::Vector{MyNode}

end


MyNode() = MyNode(0,0,MyNode[])

N = 10 # number of child  

root = MyNode(0,N, [MyNode() for i in 1:N])


# in the first level l need to link the root to the child. the number of childs is 10

childs=MyNode(1,N, [MyNode() for i in 1:N])

for node in root.childs
    # add edges between root and each child , transfer the data from root to childs
        # addEdge() and TransferData() to be developed 
end


k= 100 # number of leafs

leafs=Mynode(1,k,[MyNode() for i in 1:K])


# in the second level we add edge between each child and its leafs . let's set the total number of leafs is 100 

for node in child.leafs


     # add edges between each childs with its leafs. the number of leafs of each child may differ for instance child 1 has 5 leafs child 7 has  3 leafs and so one. We just need to have the total number of leafs equals 100.
  # addEdge() and TransferData() to be developed 


end
```

Thank you for helps

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the DataStructures.jl package? On the other hand, I have also wondered what the best (most performant) way of implementing a tree in Julia is.

Comment: l'm working on it but no results until now, l keep working. yes l took a look at the DataStructures.jl package but there is not any library for generic tree. we just have balanced_tree.jl  https://github.com/JuliaLang/DataStructures.jl/blob/master/src/balanced_tree.jl

Comment: David P. take a look at my rudimentary implementation